# React native and Firebase promises - weird side effect on render

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, setstate

I'm using two chained firebase requests in my code. the first one is fetching all the reviews, then I iterate trough all the results, firing a second firebase request for each element in loop.

After the loop, I've updated the `state` with the new data using `setState`. And that  update is making my GUI transparent, like so:

[image]

the bottom part is randomly transparent each time, sometimes the render is visible a bit, sometimes not at all. When I remove the `setState` block, everything is fine.

The code in question:

```
    getReviews() {
      let reviewData = {}
      let vendorId = this.props.item.vendor_id
      let product = this.props.item.key

      firebase.database().ref('u_products/' + vendorId + '/' + product + '/reviews/').once('value', (data) => {
        reviewData = data.val()
        if (!reviewData) {
          this.setState({
            loadedReviews: true
          })
          return
        } else {
          for (var key in reviewData) {
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + reviewData[key].poster_uid + '/').once('value', (data) => {
              let userData = data.val()
              if (userData) {
                this.getUserImageUrl()
                 ...
              }
            })
          }
          this.state.reviewData = reviewData
            this.setState({
              dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(reviewData),
              loadedReviews: true,
            })
        }
      })
    }
```

Intended behaviour is first firebase request -> second one iterating for all the results from the first request ->setState.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: One of the most common questions of all time; your final `setState()` is executed way before the individual requests finish. You even have the potential solution: Promises, in your title, but I don't see you using any.

Comment: According to the Firebase docs, Their functions are Promises by them selves. I'm obviously new to promises, been trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @ChrisG but shouldn't the `for` loop "wait" until the firebase request inside is done before making the next iteration?

Comment: No, because the loop has no clue that the `.once()` call runs asynchronously. You have to provide a callback function because the operation started by the `.once()` call will finish at some arbitrary point later in time, and the callback contains further processing. The `.once()` itself however is done, and the loop proceeds. One way to solve this is to update the state inside the callback, where you have your `...`

Comment: @ChrisG I've tried updating state inside the callback, and that code is only   executing for the last iteration which was weird to me. I can use conventional Promises with `resolve` and `reject`, but Firebase code doesn't have that. Could you do a simple "multiple firebase executions inside a loop" code snippet, I really feel that when I see a concrete example, I'll get a hang of it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firebase's `.once()` returns a `Promise`, so what you need to do is create an array of Promises, then call `Promise.all(array).then((arrayOfData) => { ... });`

You can now process the resulting array, then call `.setState()`

Here's a mockup:

```js
/* firebase mockup */
function Result(url) {
  this.url = url;
  this.once = function(param, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var data = {
          val: () => {
            return this.url + " query result";
          }
        };
        resolve(data);
      }, Math.random() * 500 + 1000);
    });
  };
}
var firebase = {
  database: function() {
    return firebase;
  },
  ref: function(url) {
    return new Result(url);
  }
};

var reviewData = {
  "test": {
    poster_uid: "testData"
  },
  "2nd": {
    poster_uid: "2ndData"
  }
};

// ACTUAL IMPORTANT CODE BELOW #################

var arrayOfPromises = [];
for (var key in reviewData) {
  arrayOfPromises.push(firebase.database().ref('users/' + reviewData[key].poster_uid + '/').once('value'));
}
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
  arrayOfResults.map((data, i) => {
    let userData = data.val();
    if (userData) {
      console.log(i, userData);
    }
  });
  console.log("setting state now");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I've made my code work by using the exact approach (putting all promises in array and then `promise.all()`. I will review your code and see if it has any improvements (it probably does :)) Now I have a concrete examples which I can expand for future use :)